# Prefill form based on URL parameters javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, url, parameters

I'm passing name & email through URL parameters from a popup form like this
xyz.com?om_email=test%40test.com&om_name=Test

I need these two forms prefilled on xyz.com site

```html
<p>
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="email" name="email">
</p>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: It isn't clear if xyz.com is your own site of a third-party (either way the question is horribly under-researched).

Answer (score 0):

More context would be nice, but try this:

I used a test URL string to allow the example to work, but on the actual site, replace params variable with the one that is commented, (hint: `window.location.search`) to extract the parameters from the URL.

There are different ways to do this, but I created an object from the parameter string then looped over the inputs and updated their value by matching the data object key to the input value name attribute.

Note: Be sure to run the JavaScript after the page loads.

```js
var url = "xyz.com?om_email=test%40test.com&om_name=Test";
var params = "om_email=test%40test.com&om_name=Test".split("&");
//use this on the actual site to extract parameters from the url
//var params = window.location.search.slice(1).split("&");
//convert the params to an object
var data = params.reduce((obj, param) => {
  var pair = param.split("=");
  return { ...obj,
    [pair[0].replace("om_", "")]: decodeURIComponent(pair[1])
  }
}, {});
//console.log({data});
//insert values by matching input name to data object key
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(input => input.value = data[input.name]);
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="email" name="email">
</p>
```

Comment: It's working. But the name & email stays for 1 sec and then it's blank again.

Comment: There might be another script that is clearing that value after this script runs. Without more context I can't be sure what's going on there. Is it just name and not email? It's a bit of a hack, but you could try delaying the form fill script using: setTimeout(() => { /*script goes here*/}, 5000);

5000 = 5 seconds, but feel free to play with that value to see if the delay helps at all. Otherwise I need more information.

Answer (score -1):

This is how to autofill a form using HTML5.

`<input value="valuehere">`

Comment: HTML 5 forbids end tags on input elements.